# what are the differences between a page component and other components in CQ

Tags: components, aem

Are there any specific rules about how this page component is processed versus regular component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page component IS a regular component. Theoretically you could use any component as a page component. 
It is just a naming convention to name the outermost component as page component, as it is responsible for rendering a page, whereas all the components included in the page component will only render part of a page. 
And the dialog of the component you set as your template's page component will be used as page properties dialog instead of being a standard component dialog in the WYSIWYG part...

Answer (score 1):

When a template is created, it is usually backed up(`sling:resourceType` of the template points to page component.) by a page component to render the initial view.

To give you an example, if you want to create a template which can accommodate any component, you would write this code to include the `parsys` component in your **page component.** So when you create a page of this template, the page will open up with just the `parsys` component. You can then construct the overall page by dragging and dropping other **regular components** like header, footer etc onto the `parsys` created in the page component.